Difference Between Eli and Samuel's sons and their punishment
Can you help me reconcile this the best way possible?
In 1 Samuel 2, we see that Eli had wicked sons.
Then in 1 Samuel 8, we also see that Samuel's sons had sinned against the Lord too.
I was wondering why it was that Eli, along with his sons, was punished greatly but Samuel was not.
Does it has something to do with the gravity of their sins?

Looking at chapter 2, I think we can note some key differences both between the sins of the sons and the roles of their fathers.
Eli's sons were violating the laws of the sacrifices (2:13-16). They were committing adultery, possibly rape, with women who came to worship God at the tabernacle (2:22). Both these sins were directly connected the worship of God and their role as priests. As a result, they brought the worship of God into disrepute and turned people away from the Lord's sacrifices, which is described as a "very great" sin (2:17). Eli was aware of his sons' sin, but apart from telling them off did nothing to stop it - when we get to chapter 4, they're still serving with the Ark of the Covenant. In the prophecy pronouncing judgment on Eli and his sons, in verse 29 God explains the reason behind the judgment. To all of them He says "you're trampling on My sacrifices", and while Eli's part seems more passive, his failure to take action shows that "you've chosen your sons over Me".
Now let's look at the story of Samuel's sons in chapter 8. In short, Samuel appointed his sons as judges (8:1), they took bribes (8:3), the elders came to Samuel and said "we have a problem here - and we know the solution" (8:4-5).
There are some pretty big differences here. Comparing first the sons. What Samuel's sons did is a big deal. However, it's not directly tied to worship. They didn't bring God into disrepute. For that reason, while Eli's sons clearly deserved death, for Samuel's sons public humiliation and loss of position may have been sufficient (it's worth noting that, as far as I'm aware, their further fate isn't recorded, which leaves open the possibility of further consequences). Comparing Samuel and Eli, we see that Eli's passivity made him a willing participant in his sons' sins. We don't have any reason to assume that's the case with Samuel. His sons took bribes to judge unjustly; that's not something Samuel could necessarily have known before appointing them as judges. While Eli was told about his sons and did nothing, when the elders told Samuel about his sons, they've already decided what action to take. We therefore can't assume that Samuel shared in the guilt of his sons in the same way that Eli did, hence no punishment for Samuel.

The problem with Eli seems to be his double-mindedness. On one hand, he did not approve the actions of his two sons and did rebuke them (1 Samuel 2:24-25). On the other, however, he participated in their transgressions by eating from the meat they illegal obtained. They were taking the flesh by force. And not only the parts of the offerings that belonged to the priests, but whatever they desired. They were also roasting their meat with the fat still attached, knowing that all the fat belonged to God. 1 Samuel 2:13-16:

Now it was the practice of the priests that, whenever any of the
people offered a sacrifice, the priest’s servant would come with a
three-pronged fork in his hand while the meat was being boiled  and
would plunge the fork into the pan or kettle or caldron or pot.
Whatever the fork brought up the priest would take for himself. This
is how they treated all the Israelites who came to Shiloh.  But even
before the fat was burned, the priest’s servant would come and say to
the person who was sacrificing, “Give the priest some meat to roast;
he won’t accept boiled meat from you, but only raw.”  If the person
said to him, “Let the fat be burned first, and then take whatever you
want,” the servant would answer, “No, hand it over now; if you don’t,
I’ll take it by force.”

Leviticus 7:29-32:

“Say to the Israelites: ‘Anyone who brings a fellowship offering to
the LORD is to bring part of it as their sacrifice to the LORD.  With
their own hands they are to present the food offering to the LORD;
they are to bring the fat, together with the breast, and wave the
breast before the LORD as a wave offering.  The priest shall burn the
fat on the altar, but the breast belongs to Aaron and his sons.  You
are to give the right thigh of your fellowship offerings to the priest
as a contribution.  The son of Aaron who offers the blood and the fat
of the fellowship offering shall have the right thigh as his share.
From the fellowship offerings of the Israelites, I have taken the
breast that is waved and the thigh that is presented and have given
them to Aaron the priest and his sons as their perpetual share from
the Israelites.’”  This is the portion of the food offerings presented
to the LORD that were allotted to Aaron and his sons on the day they
were presented to serve the LORD as priests.

As a result, both Eli and his sons fattened themselves on God's sacrifices.
1 Samuel 2:29:

So why do you scorn my sacrifices and offerings? Why do you give your
sons more honor than you give me—for you and they have become fat from
the best offerings of my people Israel!

1 Samuel 4:18:

When the messenger mentioned what had happened to the Ark of God, Eli
fell backward from his seat beside the gate. He broke his neck and
died, for he was old and overweight. He had been Israel’s judge for
forty years.

In contrast, Samuel never partook in the sins of his sons or benefit from them. 1 Samuel 12:1-6:

Samuel said to all Israel, “I have listened to everything you said to
me and have set a king over you.  Now you have a king as your leader.
As for me, I am old and gray, and my sons are here with you. I have
been your leader from my youth until this day.  Here I stand. Testify
against me in the presence of the LORD and his anointed. Whose ox have
I taken? Whose donkey have I taken? Whom have I cheated? Whom have I
oppressed? From whose hand have I accepted a bribe to make me shut my
eyes? If I have done any of these things, I will make it right.”  “You
have not cheated or oppressed us,” they replied. “You have not taken
anything from anyone’s hand.”  Samuel said to them, “The LORD is
witness against you, and also his anointed is witness this day, that
you have not found anything in my hand.” “He is witness,” they said.
Then Samuel said to the people, “It is the LORD who appointed Moses
and Aaron and brought your ancestors up out of Egypt.


The sins of the sons have nothing to do with the father. The Lord declares in Ezekiel 18:19-20:

19 “Yet you ask, ‘Why does the son not share the guilt of his father?’ Since the son has done what is just and right and has been careful to keep all my decrees, he will surely live. 20 The one who sins is the one who will die. The child will not share the guilt of the parent, nor will the parent share the guilt of the child. The righteousness of the righteous will be credited to them, and the wickedness of the wicked will be charged against them. (NIV)

Eli was punished according to his own sin. 1 Samuel 2:29 states:

Why do you scorn my sacrifice and offering that I prescribed for my dwelling? Why do you honor your sons more than me by fattening yourselves on the choice parts of every offering made by my people Israel?’ (NIV)

Eli, as the high priest of the Lord's dwelling, allowed his sons (also priests) to treat the Lord's offering with contempt, as described in 1 Samuel 2:12-17:

12 Eli’s sons were scoundrels; they had no regard for the Lord. 13 Now it was the practice of the priests that, whenever any of the people offered a sacrifice, the priest’s servant would come with a three-pronged fork in his hand while the meat was being boiled 14 and would plunge the fork into the pan or kettle or caldron or pot. Whatever the fork brought up the priest would take for himself. This is how they treated all the Israelites who came to Shiloh. 15 But even before the fat was burned, the priest’s servant would come and say to the person who was sacrificing, “Give the priest some meat to roast; he won’t accept boiled meat from you, but only raw.” 16 If the person said to him, “Let the fat be burned first, and then take whatever you want,” the servant would answer, “No, hand it over now; if you don’t, I’ll take it by force.” 17 This sin of the young men was very great in the Lord’s sight, for they were treating the Lord’s offering with contempt. (NIV)

